# Creating Web Bindings from a string with multiple entries using PowerShell

Tags: iis, powershell

I'm new to PowerShell and already facing a big challenge.
The goal is to read  a csv file. Each row of the file will be a  string  with binding parameters like:

> "Website1","116.167.74.172:443:www.xyz.com
>   116.167.74.174:443:www.xyz.com"
>
> "Website2",":80:www.xyz.com    116.167.74.172:80:"
>
> "Website3","116.167.75.155:443:    116.167.75.163:443:"
>
> "Website4",":80:"

The command to be used is:

```
New-WebBinding -Name "Default Web Site" -IPAddress "*" -Port 80 -HostHeader TestSite
```

The problem is: how do I read the one string and break it into 3 parameters: **IP**, **Port** and **HostHeader**, even when I don't have all the 3 parameters specified?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex with named capture groups to make this easier.  Let me suggest that you always put the port to the right of the ip address, if there is an ip address.  Then the following will do what you are looking for, assuming that a given line of the file is currently in $strLine.

```
$pattern = '"[^"]+","(?<ip_address>(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})?:?(?<port>\d{1,5})?:?(?<hostheader>.*)?'  
$strLine -match $pattern  
$ipaddress = if ($matches.ContainsKey('ip_address')) { $matches['ip_address'] } else { "*" }  
$port = if ($matches.ContainsKey('port')) { $matches['port'] } else { "80" }  
$hostheader = if ($matches.ContainsKey('hostheader')) { $matches['hostheader'] } else { "TestSite" }  

New-WebBinding -Name "Default Web Site" -IPAddress $ipaddress -Port $port -HostHeader $hostheader
```

Comment: I get: Cannot index into a null array.
At line:1 char:1
+ $ipaddress = if ($matches['ip_address'].Length -gt 0) { $matches['ip_address'] } ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray